# What Applications can use to scan?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, scanning

What Applications other than the Image Capture can be used to scan documents with a scanner?
The drivers for the scanner are installed, but I wonder if there is any good macos Application out there that does the job well?

Image Capture has many problems as many of you know if you have used it.

Comment: What are the problems that you have with Image Capture?

Comment: You haven't told us what make you have, or what's actually wrong with their structure or Apple's.

Comment: Should this get closed - here are guidelines for asking about software recommendations here. https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation

Comment: Three questions: What specific scanner are you trying to use; which version of macOS is running and; what model of Mac? If the scanner is manufactured by Epson, the Epson Scan 2 software is very robust. Check out the [driver/software page](https://epson.com/Support/Scanners/sh/s2).

Comment: I am looking for alternatives to Image Capture, if you think Image Capture is fine, it's great to have low expectations. I am also not looking for the manufactureres software, their latest release is 2020 and their software looks abandoned. I am also ready to accept that there is no useful alternative there.

Comment: @Human Please don't indulge in petty retorts. What is the problem with Image Capture? If you tell us what it doesn't do, that you want to do, then we might be in a better position to help.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  Clearly there's _something_ that Image Capture doesn't do that you want (or vice versa), and knowing what that is would increase the chance of people being able to help.  Of course, “Use XYZ instead of Image Capture” might still be the best answer — but there might be other possibilities you're not aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most notable third-party app for interfacing with scanners is VueScan:
https://www.hamrick.com

When Apple or scanner manufacturers stop supporting older devices, then it's your best, last hope.

It does require payment, with various levels depending on your need.

There are not many alternatives, given the difficulty of 'tailoring' things to the hardware. Scanners don't seem to have adopted standard communication protocols and data formats, in the same way that printers have. (As far as I can tell.)

Comment: At the 'bottom of the scale' there's always TWAIN compliance… which was fine in the 90s, but has got very creaky over the years.

Comment: This is the best option for people that want to hire software instead of firing their scanning hardware. Quality product and engineering that can breathe new life in old scanning hardware.

Comment: @Tetsujin Except that there's no generic TWAIN driver you can use as a default for any given scanner. (Apple dropped TWAIN in Mavericks.) It really is crazy that there isn't a universal protocol for such a common device.

Comment: The issue is not the driver, they are fine and installed. The scanner is also just fine, the only thing that really bugs me is Apple Image Capture.

Comment: @Human Then perhaps ask a question about what the problem is with IC...?

Comment: I'm not interested in IC, I just wanted to provide my motivation why I am looking for an alternative. hamrick.com does look interesting, even though I am not interested in their main value proposition of providing drivers for abandoned scanners. Maybe VueScan will also work with the orignal drivers and provide me a nice interface for it... I will try it. Just like Image Capture, just better.